# Output string contains weird characters

Tags: c++

This code ciphers a string and outputs ciphered. However, it outputs characters which i do not understand like ]^XC[^  CEA^

When i runn application through debugger, the output string contains those characters, \x2\x1a\x1\x1e\x1c_R\x2

Code is here

```
string key("fydfhjg74d2u1oj4134wq87uj97h31cx");
string encrypt(string msg, string key)

{
    // Make sure the key is at least as long as the message
    string tmp(key);
    while (key.size() < msg.size())
        key += tmp;

    // And now for the encryption part
    for (string::size_type i = 0; i < msg.size(); ++i)
        msg[i] ^= key[i];
'   return msg;
}
string decrypt(string msg, std::string key)
{
    return encrypt(msg, key); // lol
}

int main()
{   

    ofstream appfile("C:\\Users\\123024594\\Desktop\\cas.txt", ios_base::app);
    string message;
    cout << "Input string to be ciphered: ";
    cin >> message;
    cin.get();
    cout << std::endl;
    appfile << "Ciphered string: " << encrypt(message, key);
}
```

What are these characters ?

Comment: So your actual question is... ?

Comment: question is what are these characters

Answer (score 2):

Because you doing bitwise xor of individual characters of message and key strings. As bitwise operator doesn't necessarily result in printable character , You are getting non printed characters.

Answer (score 2):

```
// And now for the encryption part
for (string::size_type i = 0; i < msg.size(); ++i)
    msg[i] ^= key[i];    // msg[i] ^ key[i]
```

Bitwise XOR of characters (ASCII values) can result in both printable and non-printable characters, depending on the values.

Answer (score 1):

You use Bitwise XOR. This can result in ASCII characters under 32 (32 is Space and the first printable ASCII character).
If you want it printable you can encode the result in Base64 or change your encryption so the result can't go below 32.